# What is wrong with my if statement? Have I added the and and or correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, if-statement

If `$a3['rentsale']` is either A) `empty` or B) `equal` to the form entry for rentsale then this part is `true`. It returns `TRUE` (`manage.php?result=True`) when just this part of the if statement is there. But then when I added the second part (`&&`) to the if statement to also see if `$a3['propertytype']` is either A) `empty` or B) `equal` to the form entry for `propertytype` chosen it returns `FALSE` (`manage.php?result=False`). When just the first part was there and also when the second part was added, on the form submission I selected/input the option so they both equal the sql entries (`$a3[]`).

What have I done wrong?

```
$q3 = "select * from alerts";
$r3 = mysql_query($q3) or die(mysql_error());
$a3 = mysql_fetch_array($r3);

if(($a3['rentsale'] == '' || $a3['rentsale'] == $_POST['rentsale']) && ($a3['propertytype'] == '' || $a3['propertytype'] == $_POST['propertytype'])) {

header("location:manage.php?result=True");  
exit(); 

}
else {
header("location:manage.php?result=False");
exit();
}
```

Comment: logic looks fine, echo\dump all variables

Comment: dump your array and see what you're actually comparing   echo "<pre>" . print_r($_POSTtrue) . "</pre>";die;